# Remove nested array object based on id and type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Given a nested array of meals, we're trying to remove a nested object based on an `id` and `mealType` combo. We start of with 2 nested `breakfast` meals, if both are removed, we're trying to remove the parent key completely, since it is now empty.

Here is the code we have so far:

```js
var mealsList = {
    "menuGroup1": [
    {
      "id": "b1",
      "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
      "title": "Eggs",
      "mealType": "breakfast"
    }, {
      "id": "b2",
      "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
      "title": "Sandwich",
      "mealType": "breakfast"
    }
  ],
  "menuGroup2": [
    {
      "id": "b2",
      "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
      "title": "Fruits",
      "mealType": "snack"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(mealsList);

const removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  // pseudocode
  // mealsList.*.where("id" == id && "mealType" == mealType).remove();
}

// Remove breakfast with id and meal_type
// removeItem(id, mealType)
removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log('removed b1 breakfast, mealsList should only contain b2 object');
console.log(mealsList);

removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log('removed b2 breakfast, mealsList should only contain menuGroup2, as menuGroup1 is now empty');
console.log(mealsList);
```

The thing is we're trying to remove the nested meal object in `removeItem` without explicitly passing `menuGroupX`, instead, we're trying to target the nested `mealsList` object based on the `id` and `mealType`. The pseudo code is using a `*` to show that.

The `console.log` statements show the expected outcome in terms of how the `mealsList` should render under them.

We're looking for something short and sweet, ideally a one liner, even if that means using a lodash solution for simplicity.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3mvto7h/4) *(Code In JS tab)*

Any idea what to put instead of the pseudocode in `removeItem` to have the `mealsList` remove the specific items?

Comment: I don't know if it's good practice to create JS object as JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution which iterates over the keys of `mealsList`, filtering by `id` and `mealType` and then comparing the length of the resultant array to 0; if it is 0 that key is deleted from `mealsList`:

```js
var mealsList = {
  "menuGroup1": [{
    "id": "b1",
    "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
    "title": "Eggs",
    "mealType": "breakfast"
  }, {
    "id": "b2",
    "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
    "title": "Sandwich",
    "mealType": "breakfast"
  }],
  "menuGroup2": [{
    "id": "b2",
    "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH",
    "title": "Fruits",
    "mealType": "snack"
  }]
};

console.log(mealsList);

const removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  Object.keys(mealsList).forEach(k => (mealsList[k] = mealsList[k].filter(m => m.id != id || m.mealType != mealType)).length == 0 && delete mealsList[k]);
}

// Remove breakfast with id and meal_type
// removeItem(id, mealType)
removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log('removed b1 breakfast, mealsList should only contain b2 object');
console.log(mealsList);

removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log('removed b2 breakfast, mealsList should only contain menuGroup2, as menuGroup1 is now empty');
console.log(mealsList);
```

Comment: I like it; surprisingly readable. Can be made even shorter if OP changes mealsList to mL.

Comment: Very nice and clean one liner with pure JS, very readable, and works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use lodash's [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues) to map the array keys in your object to exclude any objects which contain the `id` and `mealType` passed into your function. You can then use [`_.omitBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omitBy) to remove any keys which have an empty array as their value:

```js
let mealsList = { "menuGroup1": [ { "id": "b1", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Eggs", "mealType": "breakfast" }, { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Sandwich", "mealType": "breakfast" } ], "menuGroup2": [ { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Fruits", "mealType": "snack" } ] };

const removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  mealsList = _.omitBy(_.mapValues(mealsList, arr => _.filter(arr, o => o.id !== id || o.mealType !== mealType)), _.isEmpty);
}

removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A vanilla way could be to first convert your `mealsList` into an array of entries, and then filter the inner arrays of the entires with `.map()` and `.filter()`. Then, once you're done, you can rebuild the object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
let mealsList = { "menuGroup1": [ { "id": "b1", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Eggs", "mealType": "breakfast" }, { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Sandwich", "mealType": "breakfast" } ], "menuGroup2": [ { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Fruits", "mealType": "snack" } ] };

const removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  mealsList = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(mealsList).map(([k,vals]) => [k, vals.filter(o => o.id !== id || o.mealType !== mealType)]).filter(([, {length}]) => length > 0)
  );
}

removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
```

A more browser compatible version of the above (without Object.fromEntries()):

```js
let mealsList = { "menuGroup1": [ { "id": "b1", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Eggs", "mealType": "breakfast" }, { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Sandwich", "mealType": "breakfast" } ], "menuGroup2": [ { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Fruits", "mealType": "snack" } ] };

const removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  mealsList = Object.assign({},
    ...Object.entries(mealsList).map(([k,vals]) => [k, vals.filter(o => o.id !== id || o.mealType !== mealType)]).filter(([, {length}]) => length > 0).map(([key, val]) => ({[key]: val}))
  );
}

removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
```

Ideally, your `mealsList` would be an array though, as it is a *list*, which would make working with your data more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for showing both ways, upvoted! I accepted the other answer as it's a very clean one liner with pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can do through `reduce` and `filter`.

```js
let mealsList = { "menuGroup1": [ { "id": "b1", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Eggs", "mealType": "breakfast" }, { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Sandwich", "mealType": "breakfast" } ], "menuGroup2": [ { "id": "b2", "menuId": "FRPUbgmMiaNH", "title": "Fruits", "mealType": "snack" } ] };

const  removeItem = (id, mealType) => {
  mealsList = Object.entries(mealsList )
  .reduce((output, [key, value]) => {
    const filterDetail = value.filter(val => (val.id!==id || val.mealType!==mealType))
    if(filterDetail.length> 0) output[key] = filterDetail;
    return output;
  }, {});
};

removeItem('b1', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
removeItem('b2', 'breakfast');
console.log(mealsList);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of `reduce` in this case?